# Ngrx/store - Action creators using Class vs Action creators using Factory function?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, react-redux, ngrx

i'am new to Ngrx/Store, so while on my journey to learn this redux-pattern approach, i encounter Action creators which can create an action and this can be done in multiple ways:

**1) Creating an action via a class.**

```
class OrderFood implements Action {
readonly type = OrderActionTypes.ORDER_FOOD;
readonly payload: { dish: string };
constructor(dish: string) {
this.payload = { dish };
 }
}
```

and then in order to dispatch the action we have to create a new instance of the class:

```
this.store.dispatch(new OrderFood ({ dish: 'spaghetti carbonara' }));
```

**2) Creating an action via a factory function.**

The function returns the action object based on the function’s input and sets the type.

```
const orderFood = ({ dish }: { dish: string }) => ({
type: OrderActionTypes.ORDER_FOOD,
payload: { dish }
});
```

and then again to dispatch the action we call the function:

```
this.store.dispatch(orderFood({ dish: 'spaghetti carbonara' }));
```

So my question is among these two ways, which one is the most efficient way of creating an action and what is the difference among these?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

They do exact the same thing, the only difference is that the action is created via a class or via a function.

We're currently looking into making a factory function approach a first class member within NgRx - for more info see https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/1570